# weback throws error when compiling scss components into one css style

Tags: webpack

I have the following:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'jsx');

var config = {
    entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [
            {
                test : /\.jsx?/,
                include : APP_DIR,
                loader : 'babel'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader") },

            {
              test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png)$/,
              loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]'
            }
            // { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            //     fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
            //     loader: "css-loader"
            // }) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {allChunks: false})
    ]

};

module.exports = config;
```

and index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import axios from 'axios';

import Forms from './forms/forms.jsx';

import './../public/sass/typography.scss';
import './../public/sass/main.scss';
import './../public/sass/navigation.scss';
import './../public/sass/buttons.scss';
import './../public/sass/forms.scss';
import './../public/sass/icons.scss';
import './../public/sass/layout.scss';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <header>
                <div className="inner">
                    <img src="/img/logo.png" />
                </div>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

....
```

when I run "NPM RUN DEV"

I get the following erros:

```
ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 21:0-43

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 23:0-37

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 25:0-43

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 27:0-40

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 29:0-38

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 31:0-38

ERROR in ./jsx/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'autoprefixer-loader' in /Users/alessandro.santese/Desktop/Alessandro/AIA/projects/accenture-tshirtbuilder/tshirtbuilder/jsx
 @ ./jsx/index.jsx 33:0-39
```

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
npm install autoprefixer-loader
```

and you should be fine. You're using it here:

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader")
```

Keep in mind that it is deprecated: [autoprefixer-loader on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-loader)